# Capture transparent WPF Window for streaming

Tags: c#, wpf, streaming, transparency

My problem is that (for some reason) a transparent WPF Window appears completely black when I try to capture it for streaming using [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/).

The moment i set this:

```
AllowsTransparency = true;
```

The software cannot render the window anymore. It just becomes a black rectangle. This happens regardless if the window is actually transparent or not.

[Here is an screenshot of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtcDl.png)

[I have asked this question before on their forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/capture-transparent-c-wpf-window.75380/), but the only answer I have gotten (from a developer there) is that its just a limitation and there is no solution.

What does work:

- Capturing the entire screen will display the window correctly
- Setting a colorkey to create transparency

But these are unacceptable "solutions". I need to be able to capture the window itself without modifications or reduction of performance.

The question then becomes: How do I make it work?

Comment: When you set the windows transparent you are just displaying the background color.  What you want is a layered window.  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx.  I can't find anything recent.  But you can create a layered window with CreateWindowEx().  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, this IS a layered window I have created. It works fine. That is not the issue.